# Syncing Rcpp with external headers and libraries to build a batch geocoding package

Tags: c++, r, geocoding, rcpp

Good evening.

GOAL: I am attempting to build a batch geocoding package based on the New York City Department of City Planning's Geosupport software using RCPP from within RStudio on a machine running Windows.  Geosupport returns a lot of useful information besides coordinates including building identification number and census geographies.  I think such a package has the potential to be very useful to researchers and community advocates working with NYC data.

BACKGROUND: Geosupport is available as a free download on the [NYC DCP website](http://www1.nyc.gov/site/planning/data-maps/open-data/dwn-gde-home.page). The download comes with a interface for batch geocoding (known as GBAT).  In addition, header, data and library files are provided so users can geocode from an application built using C, C++, or VB. The library files have a DLL extension and were compiled in C (not C++, I checked with one of the developers).

STATUS: Thus far, I have been able to include the header files and set up work areas.  I run into problems when I attempt to use the functions from the C libraries.   I have been reading Writing R Extensions - Using Makevars but I am still uncertain about how to proceed.  I built my package using RStudio's Rtools with RCPP and a makevars file was not generated.  I purchased Dirk's book (which is referenced in postings similar to mine) but it has not arrived, yet.

Thank you!

Gretchen

UPDATED CODE... 05.03.2016 at 19:45 EST:
Per Coatless's suggestion, I created a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/gmculp/RGBAT). I also created a Makevars.win and Makevars files and relocated my header files to inst/include.  The headers work OK but I still do not know what to do with the libraries.  Also, the underlying data files that drive the geocoder are too large for GitHub (1.85 GB).  I will try to add them using Git LFS from my home computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No book? No problem!

First, try to understand the package structure by creating a *package skeleton* via `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` or use RStudio's [`Create an Rcpp Package`](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486088-Using-Rcpp-with-RStudio) bit.

For everything else, there are lots of examples in the [vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html) and online in [Rcpp's gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org/).

First off the bat, the main reason for the difficult is the use of:

```
#include "../Include/NYCgeo.h"
```

This is not a good style as it goes against the file structure typical of R packages.

When trying to use library headers, one should opt for a package structure of either:

```
R/
src/
 |- Makevars
 |- Makevars.win
 |- header.h
 |- action.cpp
man/
DESCRIPTION
NAMESPACE
```

Under this approach, your header files are restricted solely to the package. To enable a `LinkingTo:` approach within the `DESCRIPTION` file and generally better inclusions, the structure you should aim for is:

```
R/
inst/
 |- include/
    |- header.h
src/
 |- Makevars
 |- Makevars.win
 |- action.cpp
man/
DESCRIPTION
NAMESPACE
```

Thus, in the `action.cpp` file you can just use:

```
#include <header.h>
```

vs.

```
#include "header.h"
```

Now, with that being said, contents for the `Makevars` and `Makevars.win` files in `/src` when including headers in the `/inst/include` should be:

```
PKG_LIBS = $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)
PKG_CPPFLAGS =  -I../inst/include/
```

The second line is the most important.

For a very simplistic example of file inclusions, see [sitmo](https://github.com/coatless/sitmo) {disclaimer: I wrote the R package}.

For a more intense and interesting version, see [dplyr](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/tree/master/inst/include).

If you code toss the complete code onto GitHub, more help could be provided.

Comment: Very nice, very patient.

Comment: This is excellent, Coatless!  Thank you for taking the time to craft such a thorough and accessible explanation.  I will post the code to my GitHub account.

Comment: I just updated my question to include a link to my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/gmculp/RGBAT) for this project.  I was able to get the headers to work using Coatless's response.  I am still confused about how I can adjust the Makevars/Makevars.win files to reflect the location of the dll files (see [Bin folder](https://github.com/gmculp/RGBAT/tree/master/Bin)).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to access the functions within the C library `MyLibrary.dll` using Coatless' response.

Here is my directory structure:

```
R/
inst/
  |- include/
  |- header.h
src/
  |- Makevars
  |- Makevars.win
  |- action.cpp
 bin/
  |- MyLibrary.dll
 man/
 DESCRIPTION
 NAMESPACE
```

Here is my `Makevars`/`Makevars.win` file:

```
PKG_LIBS = -L../bin -lMyLibrary
PKG_CPPFLAGS =  -I../inst/include/
```